# Build regex to find a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find out substring in following way

starting with semicolon or fullstop after that one compulsory word with double quotation mark in that entire substring and finally substring ends with fullstop or semicolon.
any suggetion to build a regex??

consider the following input in this I need to find explanation of double quoted words.See the output what I want.
Thanks

Input:

"A Equity Members" means the Persons whose respective names and address are set out in Part A, Schedule 1 and any further Persons appointed as such in accordance with provisions of clause 11;
"Act" means the Limited Liability Partnerships Act 2000, as amended from time to time;
"Affiliate"of any Person means any Person that, directly or indirectly through one or more intermediaries, controls, is controlled by or is under common control with such Person.  The term "control" means the possession, directly or indirectly, of the power to direct or cause the direction of the management and policies of a Person, whether through the ownership of voting securities, by contract or otherwise;

OutPut:

"A Equity Members" means the Persons whose respective names and address are set out in Part A, Schedule 1 and any further Persons appointed as such in accordance with provisions of clause 11;

"Act" means the Limited Liability Partnerships Act 2000, as amended from time to time;

"Affiliate"of any Person means any Person that, directly or indirectly through one or more intermediaries, controls, is controlled by or is under common control with such Person.

The term "control" means the possession, directly or indirectly, of the power to direct or cause the direction of the management and policies of a Person, whether through the ownership of voting securities, by contract or otherwise;

Comment: in your example is seems like splitting strings on the semicolon and dot character seems to do the trick. Why use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is

```
Match resul = Regex.Match(input, "(;|.)([^;|^.])+(;|.)");

        while (resul.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(resul.Value);
            resul= resul.NextMatch();
        }
```

A request to you. Please don't ask exact answer from stackoverflow. You can see the asking criteria in stackoverflow.